# How revert to tfs 2015 stock agile process template

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

After (or before) we convert from TFS 2012.2 to TFS 2015.3 (which we have done just fine in a test run) we would like to revert our team project to the standard TFS 2015 Agile process template, and no longer use the customized agile process that we had modified from TFS 2012. We are quite willing to delete all of our work items and start over, but need to keep the team project history and change sets. Anyone know how to do this? Answers to prior questions on this did not address this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it. Basically the steps require you to use a lot of `witadmin` commands. Start by deleting any work item types that were added and don't exist in the default template.

1. Then push the standard work item definition for each work item type.
2. Then push the categories
3. Then push the process configuration
4. Then delete any fields that are no longer used

That should bring you back to the standard template.

An alternative you could try is to use the WitMorph project. You can write a set of rules to migrate your data back into working order.

Comment: To be clear, we don't want our customized template to be the same as the new agile template, but rather for our team project to now use the new agile template, and for our custom process template to be deleted. Will either of these choices produce that result?

Comment: If your existing project is already configured, the only way is to 'morph' it into what you do want.

Comment: Thx Jesse. We unfortunately need for the custom process to be gone, and for our team project to be using a stock process, in order to migrate to VSTS.

Comment: Morphing will work just fine. They only need to look the same